# Is encrypting a query parameter within a URI a security best practice?

Tags: encryption, web-application, tampering, tamper-resistance, uri

**Assumption** a customer is sitting in a public area connected to a public wifi.

**Step 1.** `example.com` server sends the following information to `trustworthy.external.domain` over https:

1. `redirectPath`="`https://www.example.com/public/endpoint`"
2. `queryParam1`="`secret1`"
3. `queryParam2`="`secret2`"

**Step 2.** `trustworthy.external.domain` returns a URL back to `example.com` that looks something like:

```
https://trustworthy.external.domain.session/{unique_session_id}
```

**Step 3.** `example.com` client redirects the customer to the URL received in step 2.  The customer now has a secure connection from their web browser to `trustworthy.external.domain.session`.

**Step 4.** A form starts rendering in the customer's web browser from `trustworthy.external.domain.session`.  Javascript code running on the customer's web browser grabs the `redirectPath`, `queryParam1`, and `queryParam2` that were previously sent back in step 1 and decrypts them into plaintext on the customer's web browser.

**Step 5.** The form completes loading and the customer fills out some sensitive information and click a submit button, which transmits this sensitive information to `trustworthy.external.domain.session` over https.

**Step 6.** The customer is redirected back to `redirectPath` along with query parameters `queryParam1` and `queryParam2` over https.

**Step 7.** `example.com` gets the `redirectPath`, `queryParam1`, `queryParm2` and does a final redirect to let the customer know the entire session was a success.

**My concern** is in step 4 above where the  `queryParam1`, and `queryParam2` are visible in plaintext on the customer's web browser when viewing the `trustworthy.external.domain.session` form. When I set breakpoints in the javascript debugger, I see these two variables are decrypted and visible in plaintext.  If a bad actor manages tampers with the plaintext query parameters before the customer moves on to step 5, then the customer could be redirected anywhere in step 6.

**My idea:**
To prevent this from happening, my idea I have to modify step 1 as follows:

1. `redirectPath`= "`https://www.example.com/public/endpoint`"
2. `queryParam1`=encrypt("`secret1`")
3. `queryParam2`=encrypt("`secret2`")

Then in step 7, `example.com` receives the encrypted query parameters, which can be decrypted by us.  The decryption would fail if they were tampered with. If untampered, `example.com` and perform the redirect.

**My Question**Does my solution make sense and is it aligned with security best practices?

Comment: If you use HTTPS, no one can intercept or tamper the traffic.

Comment: @mentallurg ok, that definitely makes me feel better, but could I encrypt those query parameters regardless (using a different secret key, effectively double encrypting) ?

Comment: You can do whatever you want. But if you can't explain why you need, it will make no sense. HTTPS encrypts them already. And not only request parameters, but *everything*: URL, cookies, headers, body. Why do you want to encrypt parameters? What attack do you want to prevent?

Comment: @mentallurg I have reworded my question to clarify the concern.  Basically, I'm thinking about a scenario where a customer is sitting in a public area using a public wifi and a bad actor can pretty much see everything on the customer's laptop (browser variables , etc..).

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question. To quote the OP verbatim: "Basically, I'm thinking about a scenario where a customer is sitting in a public area using a public wifi and **a bad actor can pretty much see everything on the customer's laptop (browser variables , etc..)**" (emphasis mine)

Comment: The OP is talking about a (hypothetical) attack against the JavaScript environment within the customer's browser, caused by an attacker who is on the same public Wi-Fi as the customer. Such an attack isn't possible without major security flaws on the device -- if those exist, then there are much bigger problems than an incorrect redirect.

Comment: @Ja1024: You are right.

Comment: @user1068636: It is bad design, if one server sends sensitive data to another server via browser. Instead, servers should exchange sensitive data directly. Browser should only see references to these data, like IDs. Then A) Neither user nor an attacker can modify anything in the server; B) When the attacker sees IDs, they don't disclose anything about related data. E.g. payment ID does not tell what amount was paid.

Comment: Under the assumption that this is related to [your previous question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/274180/17569), I will reiterate what I said there and @mentallurg says in the comment above: Passing secure data in the query string is the wrong approach to take.  Don't worry about an external attacker compromising a legitimate user.  You should worry about a **malicious user** deliberately sending manipulated data to get stuff for free.  And the solution to that is to check on the backend.  **Never trust the client.**

Answer (score 0):

No, the approach you've described does not make sense.

First, merely using a public Wi-Fi doesn't mean everybody with network access can inspect the browser state or JavaScript variables. This would require access to the device itself, either physically or remotely through vulnerabilities within the device. If an attacker has achieved this, there are far bigger problems than a few URL parameters.

In general, an attacker within a public Wi-Fi can only read and/or manipulate the network traffic. To protect HTTP messages in this scenario, the solution is to use HTTPS (which you already seem to be doing). HTTPS ensures both the confidentiality and integrity of the messages, which means an attacker can neither read nor manipulate data like the URL, the headers or the body, even if they have full access to the Wi-Fi traffic.

Secondly, encryption isn't the right tool when your goal is *integrity*, i.e., making sure that an attacker cannot manipulate data. The purpose of encryption is *confidentiality*. If you want integrity, you need different methods, namely Message Authentication Codes or cryptographic signatures. It's also possible to combine confidentiality and integrity with so-called authenticated encryption. But then again, HTTPS already does that for all HTTP messages.

Last but not least, implementing your own cryptographic protection is rarely recommended. Unless you have a deep understanding of the threats, the available cryptographic methods and when to use which method, it's too easy to make a mistake. In the worst case, you *think* you've solved the problem, but the solution is in fact completely ineffective.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question. The author means, that when server A redirects to server B and later on server B is expected to redirect to server A, server B sees the entire URL including all parameters. It is obvious, because it is needed for redirection. The author wants to prevent server A from disclosing URL parameters to server B, and suggests to encrypt them. From this point of view it is not wrong. But it can be solved easier, without encryption, by using IDs or tokens instead of real contents.

Comment: No, this is not what the OP is asking. The OP specifically asks about **step 4** which consists of the *JavaScript code within the customer's web browser* (not a server) obtaining the parameters from the URL. When the OP used the JavaScript debugger, they've noticed the URL parameters appear as plaintext and can be manipulated, and now they're worried an attacker within a public Wi-Fi might also be able to manipulate the browser state -- which is clearly not the case. Again: This question is about attacks against the *client*.

Comment: You are right. Server wants to hide data not from another server, but from the user.

Comment: nit: a public endpoint can observe the **domain name** even when using HTTPS (and even if they couldn't, generally the domain will be discoverable from the destination IP anyhow).  However, the query parameters will still be encrypted, and not visible.